# Having issues with variables and outputs

Tags: github-actions

I started learning Github Actions a few days ago and I am playing around with it. I am having issues with defining outputs and using them in variables or as input values in another workflow step. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
name: Demo
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    outputs:
      paths: ${{ steps.find_path.outputs.paths }}

    steps:
      - name: Code Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Find Paths
        id: find_path
        run: |
            all_paths=$(cat document.txt)
            # some code 
            echo "::set-output name=paths::$(echo ${all_paths})"

      - name: List 
        id: list_path
        run: |
          var_paths=${{ steps.find_path.outputs.paths }}
          
          for part in ${var_paths[@]}; do 
             # parent_dir=$(cat...)
             # ....
             # some code
             echo $part
          done
```

I have a text file with some paths in it

```
/home/ubuntu
/home/ubuntu/docs
/home/ariel/code
```

I want to use the output from `find_path` step in another `list_path` step. There is some other code I didn't include as it's irrelevant to my question. So I defined the `paths` output in `find_path` step and it is basically a space-separated string `/home/ubuntu /home/ubuntu/docs /home/ariel/code` and that's format I want to have.

But I don't know how to use outputs from one step as input value in another step.

Basically,
`var_paths=/home/ubuntu /home/ubuntu/docs /home/ariel/code`
But when I loop `var_paths` I get weird errors like no such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the quotes when assigning the output from the step to the variable:

```yaml
name: Demo
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]


    steps:
      - name: Code Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Find Paths
        id: find_path
        run: |
            all_paths=$(cat document.txt)
            # some code 
            echo "::set-output name=paths::$(echo ${all_paths})"

      - name: List 
        id: list_path
        run: |
          # add quotes here
          var_paths="${{ steps.find_path.outputs.paths }}"
          
          for part in ${var_paths[@]}; do 
             # parent_dir=$(cat...)
             # ....
             # some code
             echo $part
          done
```

Misc comments:

- You don't need to declare the outputs on the job level unless the output from a step should also be the output from the job. In your case, you're only using the output between steps.
- The checkout action is available in `v3`