# debugging no such file or directory

Tags: github-actions

I keep getting this no such file or directory error in my workflow but I don't know why as I don't even need to have any kind of files or directories at all.

This is structure of my github repository

```
.github
 -- workflows
 ----my_workflow.yml
README.md
yoga.txt
```

This is my .yml file.

```
name: Exercises 
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  first:
    runs-on: [ ubuntu-latest ]
    outputs:
      pose_output: ${{ steps.read_file.outputs.pose_output }}

    steps: 
      - name: Get COde
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Read from file
        id: read_file
        run: |
            poses=$(cat yoga.txt)
            echo $poses
            echo "::set-output name=pose_output::$(echo ${poses})"  
      

      - name: List all 
        id: list_all
        run: |
          POSES=${{ steps.read_file.outputs.pose_output }}
          
          for input in ${POSES[@]}; do echo $input; done;
```

`yoga.txt` is basically a string, it's not an array, it's a bunch of words separated by space

`input1 input2 input3` etc.

I have two problems:

1. Outputs - how to use them the right way? As you can see I pass the output of my `read_file` step to the next step, but then I declare another variable to basically pass that output to variable which I can use in `for` loop. I know this is simple script and I can do this in one step but I want to practice.
2. The first step runs successfully and when I `echo $poses` I get `input1 input2 input3` but in next step `list_all` when I want to list all inputs via for loop I get `input1 no such file or directory`. It makes no sense.

Comment: Apparently, the issue is related to lack of quoting. What I changed `POSES="${{ steps.read_file.outputs.pose_output }}"`. What a silly mistake. I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71829189/having-issues-with-variables-and-outputs/71837991#71837991

Comment: These two questions are *suspiciously* similar..

Comment: Yes, I should've read other questions posted before posting my own as there are many similar questions.